# Material UI drawer menu component page want to no import other file

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, sidebar, drawer, react-sidebar

I want to show my data in this body no need to import file navbar and sidebar after open drawer ,the sidebar menu click.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6fxD.png)
My folder file settings,Map and Dashboard.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIVNv.png)
This is my Dashboard code file. I don't want to import this navbar file and sidebar and box.Because every file need to import if i new add sidebar menu. I don't want this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdFUW.png)
?

```
import React from 'react';
import Sidebar from './sidebar';
import Navbar from '../Nav/Navbar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <>
    <Navbar/>
    <Box height={ 50 } />
    <Box sx={{display : "flex"}}>
      <Sidebar/>
      <Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 3 }}>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      </Box>
    </Box>
    </>
  )
}
export default Dashboard
```

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.